# HTML add text under a list of images with "overflow-x:scroll"

Tags: html, css

Currently, I can do the css-overflow-x with a list of images with the following html code.

```
<div id="category" style="overflow-x:scroll; width:100%; white-space: nowrap; height:25%;">
    <a href="index.html"><img id="category_1" width="auto" height="50%" src="icon_1_d.png" style="position: relative; top:10%;"/></a>
    <a href="index2.html"><img id="category_2" width="auto" height="50%" src="icon_2_d.png" style="position: relative; top:10%;"/></a>
    <a href="index3.html"><img id="category_3" width="auto" height="50%" src="icon_3_d.png" style="position: relative; top:10%;"/></a>
</div>
```

And the following is the sample figure.
[image]

But now, I need to add description for each of the categories, e.g. desc_1 for category_1.
Like this,
[image]

I modified the code as follows

```
<div id="category" style="overflow-x:scroll; width:100%; white-space: nowrap; height:25%;">
    <div style="position: relative; top:10%;" width="auto" height="50%">
        <a href="index.html"><img id="category_1" width="auto" height="50%" src="icon_1_s.png"/></a>
        <p style="color: red">desc_1</p>
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative; top:10%;" width="auto" height="50%">
        <a href="index2.html"><img id="category_2" width="auto" height="50%" src="icon_2_d.png"/></a>
        <p style="color: red">desc_2</p>
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative; top:10%;" width="auto" height="50%">
        <a href="index3.html"><img id="category_3" width="auto" height="50%" src="icon_2_d.png"/></a>
        <p style="color: red">desc_3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it has the following problems.

(1) The images size will be 100% and cannot be resized to 50%

(2) It will lose "overflow-x:scroll" style, which means the category cannot be scroll horizontally.

Anyone has any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Eric

Comment: want like this ? http://jsbin.com/pavivuce/1/edit

Comment: is that example work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Check Below CSS Code

```
#category, p, img, div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is just to limit/resize the width, try use `max-width` instead:

```
max-width: 50%;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6stwY/

Answer (score 0):

I've made change to your existing code

```
<div id="category" style="overflow-x:scroll; width:100%; white-space: nowrap; height:25%;">
    <a href="index.html" style="display: inline-block;">
        <img id="category_1" width="auto" height="50%" src="icon_1_d.png" />
        <span style="display: block; text-align: center;">test 1</span>
    </a>
    <a href="index2.html" style="display: inline-block;">
        <img id="category_2" width="auto" height="50%" src="icon_2_d.png" />
        <span style="display: block; text-align: center;">test 2</span>
    </a>
    <a href="index3.html" style="display: inline-block;">
        <img id="category_3" width="auto" height="50%" src="icon_3_d.png" />
        <span style="display: block; text-align: center;">test 3</span>
    </a>

</div>
```

with the image, is it always going to be the same size? or you always want to use 50%? Just wondering because normally when i develop, it's usually the same size.

Answer (score 0):

propose a variant of the solution

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kwzxb)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="galleryItem">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgsrc.ru/images/reco/140/windkitten_38083968.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="galleryItem">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgsrc.ru/images/reco/140/windkitten_38083968.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>
      <div class="galleryItem">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgsrc.ru/images/reco/140/windkitten_38083968.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="galleryItem">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgsrc.ru/images/reco/140/windkitten_38083968.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>
      <div class="galleryItem">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgsrc.ru/images/reco/140/windkitten_38083968.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="galleryItem">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgsrc.ru/images/reco/140/windkitten_38083968.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>
      <div class="galleryItem">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgsrc.ru/images/reco/140/windkitten_38083968.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="galleryItem">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgsrc.ru/images/reco/140/windkitten_38083968.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>
      <div class="galleryItem">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgsrc.ru/images/reco/140/windkitten_38083968.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="galleryItem">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgsrc.ru/images/reco/140/windkitten_38083968.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 30px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.galleryItem {
    color: #797478;
    font: 10px/1.5 Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    float: left;
}

.galleryItem h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.galleryItem img {
    max-width: 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.galleryItem {
    color: #797478;
    font: 10px/1.5 Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    float: left;    

    width: 16%;
    margin:  2% 2% 50px 2%; 
}

/* MEDIA QUERIES*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 940px),
only screen and (max-device-width : 940px){
    .galleryItem {width: 21%;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 720px),
only screen and (max-device-width : 720px){
    .galleryItem {width: 29.33333%;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 530px),
only screen and (max-device-width : 530px){
    .galleryItem {width: 46%;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 320px),
only screen and (max-device-width : 320px){
    .galleryItem {width: 96%;}
    .galleryItem img {width: 96%;}
    .galleryItem h3 {font-size: 18px;}
    .galleryItem p, {font-size: 18px;}
}
```